# Getting Error for if condition - TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool

Tags: python

```
spam = ("make a lot of money" or "buy now" or "subscribe this" or "click this")
letter = '''There's a letter, buy now and subscribe this'''
if (spam == "make a lot of money" or "buy now" or "subscribe this" or "click this") in letter:
    print("It's spam")
else:
    print("It's not a spam")
```

O/p -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tutema3\Documents\Python\Manish\practice.py", line 3, in <module>
    if (spam == "make a lot of money" or "buy now" or "subscribe this" or "click this") in letter:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

or

```
spam = ("make a lot of money" or "buy now" or "subscribe this" or "click this")
letter = '''There's a letter, buy now and subscribe this'''
if spam in letter:
    print("It's spam")
else:
    print("It's not a spam")
```

O/p

```
It's not a spam
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `if (spawn == a or b) in letter` even *intended* to mean? Putting aside the issue of `or` and `==` not working the way you expect (see the linked duplicate), you want to check whether the presence or absence of a string is contained in another list? Take a breath and make sure you understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: `spam = (x or y or z)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Have you tried *print(spam)*. You should . You'll find it illuminating. I recommend: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: letter = '''There's a letter.'''
if (letter == "make a lot of money" or "buy now" or "subscribe this" or "click this"):
    print("It's spam")
else:
    print("It's not a spam")


It is always returning  -- It's a spam.